# Change color of SVG path, and underline href

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to change color of both a SVG path, and in the same time underline a href.

If i hover a SVG path, it changes fill color. But, i also want to add a corrosponding href, and if that is hovered, it should underline and the SVG path should change fill color.

```
    <svg width="480" height="660" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <metadata id="metadata31">image/svg+xml</metadata>
    <g>
      <title>Karta</title>
      <g id="g4436">
       <path fill="#C5EF6E" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="4" id="Norrbotten" d="m396.27551,46.7125l-6.5,15.875l-5.625,5.0625l-3.43753"/>
       <path fill="#C5EF6E" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="4" id="Lappland" d="m346.77551,10.15l-7.875,1.4375l3.81247,5.25l0.75003,5.0625l-1.375,6.0625l-2.3125"/>
    </g>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

And the style

```
svg #Norrbotten:hover{
    fill: #408927;
}
svg #Lappland:hover{
    fill: #408927;
}
```

The URL is currently like this:

```
<a href="#" class="Norrbotten">Norrbotten</a>
<a href="#" class="Lappland">Lappland</a>
```

But the way to go is maybe to add a class? And do it with jQuery?

## **My question**

How can i change fill color of SVG path, at the same time the href is being underlined?

And if the SVG path is hoverd, how can the href be underlined?

Comment: The `anchors` are outside the `svg`? Then you will have to do it with `javascript`. BTW, you can't have a duplicated ID. Replace `id="Norrbotten"` with `class="Norrbotten"`.

Comment: The `anchors` are indeed outside `<svd>`. My bad, should be class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to trigger the `:hover` within javascript. So instead of doing that, I just added a `class`.

**CSS**

```
svg .Norrbotten:hover, svg .Norrbotten.hovered { fill: #408927; }
svg .Lappland:hover, svg .Lappland.hovered { fill: #408927; }

a { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover, a.hovered { text-decoration: underline; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.Norrbotten').hover(
  function() {
    $('.Norrbotten').addClass('hovered');
  }, function() {
    $('.Norrbotten').removeClass('hovered');
  }
);

$('.Lappland').hover(
  function() {
    $('.Lappland').addClass('hovered');
  }, function() {
    $('.Lappland').removeClass('hovered');
  }
);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3k78j2u/)

Comment: Its works kinda =) When i hover the SVG it changes class, and also the href. But when hovering the href, the SVG doesent get filled

Answer (score 1):

Put the SVG inside the `<a>` and do `a:hover .Norrbotten {fill:red;}`